# Overfitting in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, vgg16

I am training a VGG net on STL-10 dataset

I am getting Top-5 validation accuracy about 98% and Top-1 validation accuracy about 83%

But both the Top-1 and Top-5 Training accuracy is reaching 100%

Does this mean that the network is over-fitting? Or not?

Code::

```
def conv2d(inp,name,kshape,s):
    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        kernel = get_weights('weights',shape=kshape)
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(inp,kernel,[1,s,s,1],'SAME')
        bias = get_bias('biases',shape=kshape[3])
        preact = tf.nn.bias_add(conv,bias)
        convlayer = tf.nn.relu(preact,name=scope.name)
    return convlayer

def maxpool(inp,name,k,s):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(inp,ksize=[1,k,k,1],strides=[1,s,s,1],padding='SAME',name=name)

def loss(logits,labels):
    labels = tf.reshape(tf.cast(labels,tf.int64),[-1])
    #print labels.get_shape().as_list(),logits.get_shape().as_list()
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels,logits=logits,name='cross_entropy_per_example')
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy,name='cross_entropy')
    total_loss = tf.add(tf.reduce_sum(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)),cross_entropy_mean,name='total_loss')
    return total_loss

def top_1_acc(logits,true_labels):
    pred_labels = tf.argmax(logits,1)
    true_labels = tf.cast(true_labels,tf.int64)
    #print pred_labels.get_shape().as_list(),true_labels
    correct_pred = tf.cast(tf.equal(pred_labels, true_labels), tf.float32)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))
    return accuracy

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    conv1 = conv2d(feed_images,'conv1',[3,3,3,64],1)
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1,'conv2',[3,3,64,64],1)
    pool1 = maxpool(conv2,'pool1',2,2)
    #size = [N,48,48,64]
    conv3 = conv2d(pool1,'conv3',[3,3,64,128],1)
    conv4 = conv2d(conv3,'conv4',[3,3,128,128],1)
    pool2 = maxpool(conv4,'pool2',2,2)
    #size = [N,24,24,128]
    conv5 = conv2d(pool2,'conv5',[3,3,128,256],1)
    conv6 = conv2d(conv5,'conv6',[3,3,256,256],1)
    pool3 = maxpool(conv6,'pool3',2,2)
    #size = [N,12,12,256]
    conv7 = conv2d(pool3,'conv7',[3,3,256,512],1)
    conv8 = conv2d(conv7,'conv8',[3,3,512,512],1)
    pool4 = maxpool(conv8,'pool4',2,2)
    #size = [N,6,6,512]
    conv9 = conv2d(pool4,'conv9',[3,3,512,512],1)
    conv10 = conv2d(conv9,'conv10',[3,3,512,512],1)
    pool5 = maxpool(conv10,'pool5',2,2)
    #size = [N,3,3,512]
    flattened_pool5 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(pool5)
    fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(flattened_pool5,1024,weights_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(tf.constant(0.001, dtype=tf.float32)))
    dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1,keep_prob)
    fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dropout1,1024,weights_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(tf.constant(0.001, dtype=tf.float32)))
    dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2,keep_prob)
    logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(dropout2,10,activation_fn=None,weights_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(tf.constant(0.001, dtype=tf.float32)))

    cost = loss(logits,feed_labels)

    opt_mom = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=lr,momentum=0.9)
    opt = opt_mom.minimize(cost)

    acc = top_1_acc(logits,feed_labels)
```

Comment: You have to test it using data that has not been used in your training set.

Comment: Yes I am using separate data for validation and training @Media

Comment: 83% and 100% is high variance problem. You are overfitting. try to use dropout in your fully connected layers.

Comment: @Media I have used dropout of 50% and also data augmentation

Comment: So, essentially, overfiting is measured using the Top-1 accuracy. I have tried all methods except batch-normalization, but this difference in the two accuracy values still remain

Comment: Try to decrease the number of parameters by diminishing the number of filters and the number of nodes in your fully connected layer. Batch normalisation does not have too much effect in overfitting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79897/discussion-between-siladittya-and-media).

Comment: @Media 
as I was using VGG 13 architecture already, I decreased the number of nodes in FC layers from 4096 to 2048 and also decreased the number of filters in the 7th and 8th conv layers from 512 to 256. But I see that the Top-1 Validation Accuracy is not increasing above 72% but Top-1 Training accuracy has already crossed 95%

Comment: @Media I tried decreasing the number of filters and nodes, both, but the difference between the Top-1 Training and Validation accuracy does not decrease

Comment: Would you please put your code?

Comment: @Media added the code of the network

Comment: Increase the dropout hyperparameter. decrease 1024 to 512. Use Adam optimiser and again tell me what happened.

Comment: @Media Top-1 training Accuracy did not increase above 20% and validation accuracy did not increase above 10%. I used keep_prob 0.7 and also adam optimizer

Comment: 0.7 is too much. set it to something like 0.55. Moreover, try to change the learning rate. a bit peculiar behaviour. You should train it at least some hours.

Comment: keep_prob -> 0.55, adam optimizer starting learning rate = 0.0001and FC layers 512 nodes, working perfect, Top - 1 training accuracy and validation accuracy 88% and 77% respectively and Top-5 98% both @Media

Comment: Sorry, you have used a lot of sentence fragments. I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Media I used keep_prob = 0.55 ; adam optimizer starting learning rate = 0.0001; and number of nodes in the laast two Fully connected layers = 512. After 47 epochs, I obtained Top - 1 training accuracy and validation accuracy 86% and 80% respectively and Top-5 training and val accuracy 100% and 98% repectively

Answer (score 1):

Based on your accuracies the $12 \%$ difference is introducing high variance problem which means you are overfitting. Due to the fact that the number of parameters is too many for `VGG16` and you have a moderate-size dataset which is smaller than `ImageNet` overfitting is obvious. Try to decrease the number of parameters in the bottlenecks of your model, the connections among fully connected networks and convolutional layers and fully connected layers. Moreover, try to use `AdamOptimizer` which better. Also try to train for more epochs.

Comment: If I train for more epochs then the difference between the accuracies starts increasing, so I stopped training

Comment: It depends. By choosing appropriate dropout alpha it may not.

Comment: I used 0.55 as you said. I will try with different alpha then. but using 0.55 I obtained 86% and 80% respectively

Comment: There should be a point where you stop training phase. I meant you should let your model be trained enough. It's customary to use grid search for hyper-parameter tunning.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you for you help. I had not been able to implement Adam optimizer before today, always faced problem.

Comment: @Siladittya `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I wanted to say, I always had problems using Adam Optimizer because I always had problems I mentioned in the comments